# como excluir un registro

Tags: sql-server

Tengo dos tablas una de garantia y otra de modificaciones lo que se requiere es listar todas los registros de la tabla modificaciones que no tengan garantia hice esta consulta que me funciona correctamente

```
;with
    T_GARANTIA AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM TB_GARANTIA TB WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE TB.ID_ESTADO='ACT' AND  TB.ID_CONTRATO = @ID_CONTRATO
    )
    ,
    T_CONTRATO_MODIFICACION AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM TB_CONTRATO_MODIFICACION TM WITH(NOLOCK)  WHERE TM.ID_ESTADO='ACT' AND TM.ID_CONTRATO=@ID_CONTRATO
    ),
        T_TIPO_MODIFICACION AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM TB_TIPO_MODIFICACION TPM WITH(NOLOCK)  WHERE TPM.ID_ESTADO='ACT'
    )
    Select TM1.*,'NO REGISTRADO'AS GARANTIA,CONCAT(TPM.DESCRIPCION,' ',TM1.NRO_MODIFICACION) as TIPO_MODIFICACION,ISNULL(TG2.CUSTODIO, 'NO INGRESADO') As CUSTODIA
    From  TB_CONTRATO_MODIFICACION  TM1 WITH(NOLOCK)
    Left Outer Join
    TB_GARANTIA  TG2
    ON   TM1.ID_CONTRATO_MODIFICACION = TG2.ID_CONTRATO_MODIFICACION
    INNER JOIN 
    T_TIPO_MODIFICACION TPM ON TPM.ID_TIPO_MODIFICACION=TM1.ID_TIPO_MODIFICACION
    where 
    TG2.ID_CONTRATO_MODIFICACION IS NULL 
    AND 
    TM1.ID_CONTRATO=@ID_CONTRATO    ORDER BY TM1.FECHA_SISTEMA DESC
```

Pero al momento de que el usuario de de baja a la garantia donde solo cambia el id_estado a 'Baja'
el problema es que al realizar esta eliminacion ya no va salir en la lista siendo que se la necesita para volver a registrar
estas son las dos tablas

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_GARANTIA](
    [ID_GARANTIA] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [NUMERO_GARANTIA] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [MONTO_GARANTIA] [numeric](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [ID_CONTRATO] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ID_TIPO_GARANTIA] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [ID_ASEGURADORA] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TIPO_INGRESO] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ID_OBJETO_GARANTIA] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ID_ESTADO] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [ID_CONTRATO_MODIFICACION] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_CONTRATO_MODIFICACION](
    [ID_CONTRATO_MODIFICACION] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [ID_CONTRATO] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ID_MODIFICACION] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [NRO_MODIFICACION] [int] NULL,
    [PLAZO] [int] NULL,
    [MONTO] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [ID_ESTADO] [varchar](5) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

No esta **nada claro** lo que solicitas, pero si quieres que tener en T_Garantia los que están de baja, puedes aplicar un TB.ID_ESTADO IN

Tampoco tiene mucho sentido, desde mi lado aplicar el hint WITH (noLock) para luego no ponerlo en TB_GARANTIA  TG2, con lo cual a priori, TB_Garantía esta bloqueada.
Luego si no quieres bloqueos en ninguna tabla, utiliza un nivel de aislamiento para la transacción completa. Personalmente me parece muy peligroso, trabajar sin bloqueos.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

with T_GARANTIA
     AS (SELECT *
                FROM TB_GARANTIA AS TB
                WHERE TB.ID_ESTADO IN('ACT', 'BAJA') AND TB.ID_CONTRATO = @ID_CONTRATO),
     T_CONTRATO_MODIFICACION
     AS (SELECT *
                FROM TB_CONTRATO_MODIFICACION AS TM
                WHERE TM.ID_ESTADO = 'ACT' AND TM.ID_CONTRATO = @ID_CONTRATO),
     T_TIPO_MODIFICACION
     AS (SELECT *
                FROM TB_TIPO_MODIFICACION AS TPM
                WHERE TPM.ID_ESTADO = 'ACT')
     Select TM1.*
          , 'NO REGISTRADO' AS GARANTIA
          , CONCAT(TPM.DESCRIPCION, ' ', TM1.NRO_MODIFICACION) as TIPO_MODIFICACION
          , ISNULL(TG2.CUSTODIO, 'NO INGRESADO') As CUSTODIA
            From TB_CONTRATO_MODIFICACION AS TM1
                      Left Outer Join TB_GARANTIA AS TG2 ON TM1.ID_CONTRATO_MODIFICACION = TG2.ID_CONTRATO_MODIFICACION
                      INNER JOIN T_TIPO_MODIFICACION AS TPM ON TPM.ID_TIPO_MODIFICACION = TM1.ID_TIPO_MODIFICACION
            where TG2.ID_CONTRATO_MODIFICACION IS NULL AND TM1.ID_CONTRATO = @ID_CONTRATO
            ORDER BY TM1.FECHA_SISTEMA DESC;
```

[Set Transaction Isolation Level](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)